# df.to_latex() table width pylatex

Tags: tables, pylatex

i am using Pylatex in order to generate automatic reports.

In order to generate Table from a dataframe i am using the following function:

```python
def createTable(doc,df,TableTitle):
    with doc.create(Table(position='htbp')) as table:
        table.add_caption(TableTitle)
        table.append(Command('centering'))
        table.append(NoEscape(df.to_latex(escape=False)))
```

The thing is i get a pdf file where some of the columns of the dataframe are sliced.

How i can fix this issue? how i can apply width parameter in this table creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! just added the two lines below:

```python
doc.packages.append(Package('adjustbox'))
doc.append(NoEscape(r'\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}'))
doc.append(NoEscape(df.describe().to_latex()))
doc.append(NoEscape(r'\end{adjustbox}'))
```

Comment: While this works, it will reduce the font size, which is not ideal. It's possible to change the setup of the table via options to the `to_latex` method, for example you can change the column types with the `column_format` option. It's hard to give more specific advice without knowing what's in the table though.

Comment: Thanks! Basically ill try to play with the parameters of the function as well